# Generate text file based on excel sheet

Tags: java

I'm not a programmer. I'm looking for generating a script  from excel file based on the following; 
A                    B                   C
value1            Value2            MyVal1
Value3            Value4            MYVal2

I want to generate text file as the following;

Hello
I'm (Value1)
I'm looking (Value2) (MyVal1)
next
I'm (Value3)
I'm looking (Value4) (MyVal2)
next

and so on for each row in excel file
this photo clarify what i need [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIN2C.png)

Regards,

Comment: Have you tried writing any code ? Can you share your excel

Comment: The following contains many different ways to write to a file in Java: https://www.baeldung.com/java-write-to-file

Answer (score 0):

I imagine what you want is a way to read an excel file, and then output a text file in the format you have outlined above. To read an excel file, here is a fairly straightforward way of obtaining all the values by cells that you require: https://www.callicoder.com/java-read-excel-file-apache-poi/. And to write these out to a file, there's multiple ways but here is a simple tutorial to follow as well: https://www.baeldung.com/java-write-to-file